# resetting form, doesnt trigger change for checkboxes - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a class using the 'change' method like this:

```
$('.fitCheck').on('change', function() {
    label = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        label.addClass('checkedClass');
    } else {
        label.removeClass('checkedClass');
    }
});
```

I also have a reset input button, when the form is reset, and the checkboxes have been changed, my script above does not run.

Thanks for the help

** ADDED HTML ON REQUEST **

```
<form id="addItemForm" action="addItem.php" method="post">
    <div class="formWrap">
        <?php if($error)echo '<div class="errorMessage">'.$error.'</div>' ?>
        <h5> Title </h5>
            <input class="title" name="title" type="text"></input>
        <h5> Fits </h5>
            <label for="TX1Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="TX1" class="fitCheck" id="TX1Checkbox">TX1</label>
            <label for="TX2Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="TX2" class="fitCheck" id="TX2Checkbox">TX2</label>
            <label for="TX4Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="TX4" class="fitCheck" id="TX4Checkbox">TX4</label>
            <label for="VITOCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="VITO" class="fitCheck" id="VITOCheckbox">VITO</label>
        <h5 id="priceField" class="message"> Price (ex VAT) </h5>
            &pound;<input name="priceExVAT" type="text"></input>
        <h5 class="message"> Image </h5>
            <input name="image" type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"></input>
        <h5> Description </h5>
            <textarea name="body" type="text"></textarea>
        <br />
        <div class="buttonWrap">
            <button class="send positive mail left"> Upload Product </button>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="negative mail right">
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="doAction" value="1" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Added this and it works:

```
boxes = $('.fitCheck');

$('#addItemForm').on('reset', function () {
    boxes.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        boxParent = $this.parent();
        (!$this.is(':checked')) ? '' : boxParent.removeClass('checkedClass');
    });
});
```

Would have liked to not add another handler, if any suggestions, would be great.

Thanks

Comment: `label.toggleClass($(this).is(':checked'));`

Comment: Need your html and reset script

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fitCheck').on('change', function() {
    label = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        label.addClass('checkedClass');
    } else {
        label.removeClass('checkedClass');
        label.prop('checked' , false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the event in jquery ready event as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fitCheck').on('change', function() {
    label = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        label.addClass('checkedClass');
    } else {
        label.removeClass('checkedClass');
    }
});

});
```

It is recommended to assign events at **ready()** as all the DOM elements are available.

Comment: It was already in the ready() function, thanks. So far haven't come up with anything that will shorten the code :/